# Keep the same case when replacing words in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

My goal is to correct common grammar errors in messages. Here's what I currently have written:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
    String message = event.getMessage().replaceAll("(?i)dont", "don't")
            .replaceAll("(?i)youre", "you're");

    event.setMessage(message);
}
```

This works to replace `dont` with `don't`, and `youre` with `you're`. The issue is that `DONT` is replaced with `don't`, rather than `DON'T`.

How would I execute this replacement while preserving case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use capturing groups:

```java
> "DoNt".replaceAll("(?i)\\b(don)(t)\\b", "$1'$2")
"DoN't" (String)

> "YoUrE".replaceAll("(?i)\\b(you)(re)\\b", "$1'$2")
"YoU'rE" (String)
```

You should also use `\b` for a word boundary, so you don't inadvertently change words like "orthodontist" into "orthodon'tist".